# firebase cloud messaging (using app client)

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google said FCM is free. What is this mean? Can anyone explain that?

[image]

registration_ids:

This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs)       receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

At most 1000? What if i have 2000 users(tokens).

One more problem. there is some mistake in my php script, i could only send noticication to one token(top most row token from taken), plse check my send.php:

table is simple only 1 column with list of tokens.

```
<?php
require "info.php";
$message = $_POST["message"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$path_to_fcm = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$server_key = "*******************************";
$sql="select token from fcm";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$column = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 

$key=$column[0];

$headers=array('Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
'content-Type:application/json');

$fields=array('registration_ids'=>$key,
'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));

$payload = json_encode($fields);
$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
$result=curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session); 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please help I am stuck with my project.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Please review bellow example, and also take care of parameters sent to FCM server. like 'to','notification','data'

```
$registrationIds=array();

//select user RegistrationIDs/Token from DB
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql="SELECT `reg_id` from users;";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($registrationIds,$row["reg_id"]);
}
mysqli_close($con);


$msg = array(
    'body' => "My First Blog Description",
    'title' => "My First Blog"
);

$noti_key='YOUR_FCM_REGISTRATION_KEY';

$registrationIds_chunk=array_chunk($registrationIds,1000);
foreach($registrationIds_chunk as $single_chunk){
    if(count($single_chunk)==1){
        $fields = array
        (
            'to'=>$single_chunk[0],
            'notification'=> $msg
        );
    }else{
        $fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids'=>$single_chunk,
            'notification'=> $msg
        );
    }

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key='.$noti_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields, true ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
}
```

Comment: Plse rewrite the above code with given paramaters, i am not experience developer so its making me confuse.
$token (plse extract from table table_name fcm with 1 column token)
$title
$message 
(no to  need to pass extra data with notification)
use database to get tokens
plse plse

Comment: plse exclude $data (i dont want to send data)..instead include $title(notification title)..

Comment: try to print $result variable and reply here. let's check what response you got.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Firebase is free for FCM service.

registration_ids is a ID that is generated by device(Mobile) and send to server, if your app using Firebase.

Firebase use that ID and send any type of notification to number of devices.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```